# New firmware (with bug fixes) is available on the official website of the manufacturer - do I need to update via PC?

Tags: updates, ota-update, rom-update

I have [Cubot KingKong Mini 2](https://cubot.net/phones/KingKong-mini-2-specs/60) (Android 10 smartphone) and the new version of the firmware is available on the official website of the manufacturer: https://cubot.net/Support/id/60/cid/16.html#hh

[image]

It contains "***minor bug fixes***". They also gave instructions on how to update firmware: via *PC*, using *SP Flash Tool*.

My question is: does the "standard" update from *Android app settings* (`System > Advanced > System update`) also include the same bug-fixes? If so, then I don't have to do anything via *PC* & *SP Flash Tool*.

I tried to find the answer by searching on Google, and on some sites it says that "*firmware update = Android update*" (which means that I don't have to do anything via PC?), while on others it says that it is not (which means that I would have to update firmware via PC/*SP Flash Tool*?).

Comment: Usually device are getting updates as OTA update (Over The Air) and the on-device `System update` retrieves and installs them. But we are here talking about a Chinese manufacturer of cheap phones, there is everything possible. Check your system version and build number, may be you already have this "2020-11-13" update installed.

Comment: Thanks @Robert 
If I understand correctly, OTA & `System update` should also include "firmware" updates, not just updates for OS?

Comment: On Android firmware == OS. It is a common misunderstanding that there is a difference between firmware and OS, on Android they are more or less inseparable.

Comment: OS is system partition. firmware is other partitions like vendor, tee, secro, nvram, modem etc